# JavaScript - Check string with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

This piece of code should return hits = ["Heather, "Heather", "Heather"] but it doesn't. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var text = ["Heather", "kfdjsalfjdai", "fdjafhjdksafh", "Heather", "Heather", "fjdiafjdoisfhoids"];
var myName = "Heather";
var hits = [];
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === myName[i]) {
        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++); {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This functionality is builtin already `var hits = text.filter(function(s){return s===myName})`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check against `myName` variable.

```
var text = ["Heather", "kfdjsalfjdai", "fdjafhjdksafh", "Heather", "Heather", 
                                        "fsomething"];
var myName = "Heather";
var hits = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === myName) {      
            hits.push(text[i]);      
    }
}
console.log(hits);
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/pusipi/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Shyju *Could be a reason:* There's a built in function, but not sure why reinventing the wheel. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use array `filter` function:

```
var hits = text.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj === myName;
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
var text = ["Heather", "kfdjsalfjdai", "fdjafhjdksafh", "Heather", "Heather", "fjdiafjdoisfhoids"];
var myName = "Heather";
var hits = text.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj === myName;
});
console.log(hits);
```

Comment: I haven't had that function yet though. Could you help me solve this problem by using a 'simple' for loop?

Comment: Mandatory ES6 syntax: `var hits = text.filter(obj => obj === myName);`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, even if it get's the desired result.. I don't understand that function, I can't really learn from something either if I just copy-paste it.

Thank you for your answer though, I will be going with the other answer.

Comment: @Cake Just added the snippet to prove you! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar my code used the ES6 Fat Arrow Function -- that is indeed ES6 syntax.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Well, browsers **cannot accept** ES 6.

Comment: @PraveenKumar [you sure about that, mate?](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I said all browsers... `:P`

Comment: @SterlingArcher I cannot find IE 8 or 7... LoL.

Comment: Why would a legacy browser support modern technology? Microsoft is dropping IE10 support soon as is. Modern technology requires modern browsers.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Some filthy people and corporations still use IE! `:(` Too bad, can't help.

Comment: @Cake Sorry, what I meant was, I am saying there's a built-in function, which you can [learn here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and you don't need to do complex things and reinvent the wheel. Do you agree?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Yes I suppose so. I will learn that function, thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You know that not all browsers support `Array.prototype.filter()` either, right? IE8 doesn't support it. So now what, fall back to `for` loops? We move on. And the quicker we as a development community forget about the atrocities of the past, the better.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Eeeeks... I accept! LoL. You are a Mod God. So you must be right. LoL.

Comment: /me makes note to never respond to this guy cause he won't listen unless you are a mod

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory use this library answer. Here I use lodash:

```
var text = ["Heather", "kfdjsalfjdai", "fdjafhjdksafh", "Heather", "Heather", "something"],
    myName = "Heather";

var hits = _.filter(text, _.matches([myName]);
```

Explanation on what's happening because this isn't intuitive at all. _.filter does the same thing as `Array.prototype.filter` except it's faster. You can run your own tests below to get an idea:

https://jsperf.com/array-filter-vs-lodash-filter-without-bias/2

The explanation I've heard is that traditional array operations implemented by lodash (map, reduce, filter, etc.) don't have to follow the implementation as detailed by the spec.

Anyways, `_.filter` takes two arguments: a collection (array or object) and function which returns true or false. If true, it'll return the item.

`_.matches` is a convenience function which returns a function that takes an argument and matches against the contents of the provided collection.

You could write the above another way:

```
var hits = _.filter(text, function(str) {
  return str === myName
});
```

In lodash, we create functions all the time that basically executes an equality check. `_.matches` is just a convenience function to create equality check function.

Answer (score -1):

`text[i]` will never === `myName[i]`, because `text` is an array of strings, whereas `myName` is just one string. So for example, `text[1] === "Heather"`, whereas `myName[1] === "H"`. Any index of `myName` will just return one character.